# How can I find this element with this HTML on Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm having a hard time to find a way to select the link below with Selenium by it's name. I need to go by it's name as I will need to identify and select more of it.
The identification for this case is: POOL22LATECH

The xpath and CSS selector for this is related to the position on the website and not the name.

Can someone please help?

As an observation, I can't use I can't use the 'tt4', I need to identify by it's name...which, in this case is: POOL22LATECH

Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<a id="tt4" href="javascript:openViewReviewPool('20422', 'Submit for approval', 'fetchPoolAttributes', '1H');">POOL22LATECH<br>20422</a>
```

XPATH:

`//*[@id="tt4"]`

CSS Selector:

`#poolWithID_3 > td:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)`

Comment: Did my solution wored for you?

Comment: no...it says:

 Message: Given xpath expression "//a[contains(.,POOL22LATECH]" is invalid: SyntaxError: Document.evaluate: The expression is not a legal expression

Comment: You are missing `'` signs here. Please copy-paste exactly what I gave you

Comment: It says that was not possible to find it

Comment: Can you share a link to that page or all its HTML, not only the single element HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all!

I got it with: `driver.find_element_by_xpath (f"//*contains(text(),'POOL22LATECH')]")`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried XPath like this ?

```py
"//a[contains(.,'POOL22LATECH')]"
```

Answer (score 0):

To locate the element with text ***POOL22LATECH*** you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *partial_link_text*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "POOL22LATECH")
  ```
- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='openViewReviewPool'][href*='fetchPoolAttributes']")
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, 'openViewReviewPool') and contains(., 'POOL22LATECH')]")
  ```

---

To extract the text ***2*** ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over):

- Using *PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "POOL22LATECH")))
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='openViewReviewPool'][href*='fetchPoolAttributes']")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@class, 'contactAction') and starts-with(@aria-label, 'Email')][@href]//span[@class]/span")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```